# Adding pyramid_formalchemy to existing app

Tags: python, pyramid, formalchemy

Try to add pyramid_formalchemy to existing app as described in http://docs.formalchemy.org/pyramid_formalchemy/ the following way:

```
$ pcreate -s pyramid_fa myapp
```

In result inside package "myapp" directory with the same name is created, it contains three files: faforms.py, fainit.py, faroutes.py. Is it bug? When I try to create new project:

```
$ pcreate -s alchemy -s pyramid_fa myapp
```

these three files locates inside in mayapp package directly.

After adding settings to __init__.main() I try to open /admin page and get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FieldSet'
```

I use 1.3 Pyramid version.

Answer (score 0):

The pyramid_formalchemy scaffold only contains those three files, and is meant to be used along another scaffold. Both `fainit.py` and `faroutes.py` contain a `includeme` method, which mean they can be imported through pyramid's configuration system by doing this during the app setup :

```
config.include('myapp.fainit')
config.include('myapp.faroutes')
```

As for the exception, I guess it is raised by something looking for `faforms.FieldSet`, but it's hard to say without the full traceback. I can't reproduce the error (`/admin` works for me). Can you retry and confirm whether it's still broken ? If so, please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Create a file called forms.py in your application. Make sure it contains:

```
from formalchemy import FieldSet, Grid
```